# How to download images from a server

Tags: php, android, image, lazy-loading

I have an app that download some images from a server. Now app create a http post request for php script, that retrieve image (4 for each request) and sent it to my app into a json response (encoded in base 64). I put images into a ScrollView, and when user reach the end of the list, a new group of images is downloaded.
That is not the most perfotmant way, so i would use some LazyLoad libraries found on gitHub, but all of that require link to image, but i wouldn't sent in any way image link to app.
So, how can i do to retrieve images with lazy load?

Comment: So do you want to cache those image in your device???

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8562313/1761003

Comment: @Kishan yes, i would cache images into my device until current activity is running

Comment: @maven i've see that library, but in require link of image

Comment: here it is https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/sample/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/sample/Constants.java

Comment: my app shouldn't know links of images. Images are results of a query on database

Comment: `i would cache images into my device until current activity is running ` ??? Don't understand this. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Requesting images one by one or four by four does not make such a difference. In both cases you would first put a placeholder image in the imageview(s) and upon download complete and extracting done put the images in the respective imageviews if they do still exist. I suppose you put the downloaded and extracted images on the device so you can use them again when the user scrolls or starts the app again?

Comment: it's how my app current works. But app don't receive any link to images, but a json message with encoded images.
So if i want to use lazy load library i needs to use links?

Comment: Yes I understood that of course. You are not telling anything new. So why didn't you react more to the point? You do not need links to images. A link to a four image file/response is ok. Have you ever implemented a lazy image loader with image links?